# Prevent ChildComponent to be reloaded after StateHasChanged?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component with different components inside, that have different Parameter given by the parent component. In one component is, for example, a boolean. It gets the value (true) as Parameter from the parent component.
If I change the boolean value inside the child component (to false) and then something occures in the parent componet that triggers StateHasChanged, the child component refreshes with the bool Parameter from the parent component (true).

Is there any cool way to prevent that, so that the bool keeps its value?
Or do I have to do something like a callback, so that the bool inside the parent changes everytime when the bool inside the child changes? And if I have to do so, is the following the correct way, or is there an easier way?

```
Parent

<TestComponent boolChanged="this.ChangeBool" MyBool="this.myBool"></TestComponent>

@code {
    private bool myBool = true;

private void ChangeBool(bool change)
{
    this.myBool = change;
}
}


Child

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> boolChanged { get; set; }

private async Task SetBoolFalse()
{
    this.MyBool = false;
    await this.boolChanged.InvokeAsync(this.MyBool);
}
}
```

Seems like a lot of work, if there are multiple Parameters.

Comment: The Child shouldn't be setting that parameter, there is something off with your design. Consider using a different var to store the internal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Child component (TestComponent)

```
@code {
    private bool myBool; 
    [Parameter]
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> MyBoolChanged { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        myBool = MyBool;
    }

   private async Task SetBoolFalse()
   {
      myBool = false;
      await MyBoolChanged.InvokeAsync(myBool);
   }
}
```

### Parent component

```
<div>@myBool.ToString()</div>

<TestComponent @bind-Value="myBool"/>

@code {
    private bool myBool = true;
}
```

Note: You should never mutate the state of parameters. Parameter properties are used only for flowing data between components. You should define a local variable (myBool) to maintain your state. Note that I initialize the variable myBool with the value of the MyBool parameter property in the OnParametersSet life cycle method.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way doing this with more than one Parameter, when I use @bind-Value like you did?

Comment: Not sure I get you, but if you mean that you want to have two parameters sent to the child component, the first is of string type, and the second is of int type, then you can define a class with appropriate parameters and bind it to your component.

Comment: Yes, that's how it was meant. Helped me a lot, thanks.

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Little error in your Code: it has to be @bind-MyBool="myBool" instead of @bind-Value="myBool"